# ORACLE 11g SQL date query not returning data for today

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following SQL which should return all data up to 6.30am tomorrow. **It** **has been working correctly until today (30/6/2016)**.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUK.THEDATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') DAT
FROM TRUK
WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUK.THEDATE,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sysdate + 1) + 6.5/24,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') 
ORDER BY TRUK.THEDATE
```

**PROBLEM**
Today the data returned does not include data for 30th June,which i know exists but only 1st July. When i comment out the where clause, then all data is returned but of course this includes data AFTER 6.30am for the next day which i don't want returned.

I have searched in vain for an answer and would greatly appreciate some assistance with this. How Could the where clause be written differently to prevent this?

My **desired result** is that all records in the database are returned up to 6.30am the following day.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing strings, but you should be comparing dates.

Adjust your where clause to this and it'll work:

```
WHERE truk.thedate <= trunc(sysdate) + to_dsinterval('1 06:30:00')
```